# Cin Not Working in While Loop

Tags: c++

A simple code below; I'm trying to use `cin` in the `while` loop to capture the correct user input (*integer instead of string*), and it seems as if the while loop is ignoring it.

```
int main(){
     string Host = "Host: ";
     string Intro = "Type in a number. ";

     cout << Host << Intro;

     int PlayerID;
     cin >> PlayerID;

     while (cin.fail()){
         cout << endl << "Input number" << endl;
         cin >> PlayerID;
         return 0;
    }
```

The while loop gets activated as the "Input number" string pops up, however it's not giving me the chance to enter the correct input.

Comment: almost certainly a duplicate. Pretty certain we've had to answer this before.

In any case, you need to clear its flag (cin.clear() and ideally wipe its buffer too)

Comment: marginally different question but raises the same point and you can get the answer there.

Comment: You say `return 0;` inside the loop. You can't expect the program to continue after that.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me there, I found a post very similar to mine but the solution didn't help. This solution did help however. Thanks a lot.